# Does 好 + adjective with negative connotation reinforce the negative connotation or mitigate it?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, adverbs

Sometimes I heard 好 precedes an adjective which includes negative connotation (e.g. 无聊, 累).

Example:

> 好无聊啊！
>
> 好累了。

In these cases, do speakers have good or bad intentions? Specificall:

- Does it have worse intention than just these adjectives? IOW do 好 reinforce the negative connotation of the adjective?
- Does it have better intention than when these adjectives are used alone, since 好 inself has good connotation?

Or to make it easier to understand, where does 好 + adjective with negative connotation fall in the following diagram?

> [A] < 无聊 < [B] < 很无聊 < [C]

Comment: As a native speaker, I think "好" just means "very", nothing else. Besides, I really think your question is hard to understand.

Comment: 好＋形 quite ＋ adj, how ＋ adj.!
bkrs 好 II〈副〉
(1) 很, 甚, 太 [very]--表示程度, 多含感叹语气。 如: 好大的眼睛; 好深的沟; 好乔(十分古怪); 好杀(极言其好); 好是(真是, 很是)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your question, 好无聊 is almost the same intention as 很无聊。

However, they are sightly different in expressing emotions.

好无聊 is a slight complaint with a potential effort of trying to make the situation less boring.

很无聊 is just a plain statement.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, 好 in this usage is just 'very', and 'very' intensifies the degree of the property expressed.

Look for example in Baidu 好麻烦：

身为是女人我也觉得女人很麻烦。有时候也不知道为了什麼而生气。

女生大概是这个世界上最难懂的生物了，是的，我是个女的都觉得女生有时候真的好麻烦完全搞不懂在想什么，太复杂了，还是自己一个人最省心

女人哦！

Answer (score 1):

To answer you answer, yes.

好, means "very", "extremely" in this case. This is usually accompanied by strong emotions.

You can also change it into "太", "很" or "真是".